# How do I change to the noop scheduler?

Tags: kernel

I have an SSD in my laptop and I've been told that switching to the "noop" scheduler is preferred.

How do I change to the noop scheduler, and where do I make the change so that it is persistent across reboots?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Edit /etc/default/grub, such as `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, here you need to add elevator=noop.

Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash elevator=noop"`.

Then run `sudo update-grub2` and restart.

Comment: Anonymous' answer is good for changing the default across all disks on a system.  By contrast, Eliah Kagan's answer sets the default for specific disks.  For a laptop with a single drive, either works fine.  For systems with multiple disks -- most notably, disks with both SSDs and rotating drives), Eliah Kagan's answer provides finer-grained control.

Comment: The `elevator=` kernel argument was removed in kernel v5.4, which is used since Ubuntu 20.04 LTS focal. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/85c0a037dc7a1a34d6add49d6eaa2deddbf43d7b

Answer (score 31):

Suppose your hard disk is `/dev/sda`. Then you could check to see what scheduler is currently in use for it:

`cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler`

(The scheduler currently in use will be surrounded by `[` `]` brackets.)

And you could make it use the noop scheduler:

`echo noop > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler`

See [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-change-io-scheduler-for-harddisk/) for slightly more information.

To make the change persist, you can put the command in `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: I get a "permission denied" error running this, even with sudo

Comment: @LucasBustamante Are you running `sudo echo noop > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler`? That doesn't work, as the shell, which runs as your user, sets up the redirection before running the command whose output is redirected. You can use `echo noop | sudo tee /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler` instead. See [Cannot echo “hello” > x.txt even with sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/q/103643/22949) and [How to solve “permission denied” when using sudo with redirection in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/230476/22949) for more information and other approaches. (If that's not what you mean, please let me know.)

Comment: thanks for answering, that didn't help either. I'm using a NVMe SSD, I think it doesn't use the scheduler at all, from what I understood https://serverfault.com/questions/693348/what-does-it-mean-when-linux-has-no-i-o-scheduler

Answer (score 14):

[This Debian reference](https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization) shows how to dynamically detect SSDs and change the scheduler accordingly:

> In systems with different drive types you can adjust settings with a
>   udev rule (create /etc/udev/rules.d/60-ssd-scheduler.rules):
>
> # Set deadline scheduler for non-rotating disks
>
> ```
>  ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]", ATTR{queue/rotational}=="0",ATTR{queue/scheduler}="deadline"
> ```

To make sure that your kernel can detect rotational status:

```
$ for f in /sys/block/sd?/queue/rotational; do printf "$f is "; cat $f; done
/sys/block/sda/queue/rotational is 1
/sys/block/sdb/queue/rotational is 1
/sys/block/sdc/queue/rotational is 0   <=== Only this is SSD!
```

All of the above is quoted directly from the Debian reference, which has many other elements of interest to first-time SSD users.

Comment: root@titan:/home/kessaras# for f in /sys/block/sd?/queue/rotational; do printf "$f is "; cat $f; done
/sys/block/sda/queue/rotational is 0
/sys/block/sdb/queue/rotational is 0
/sys/block/sdc/queue/rotational is 1
/sys/block/sdd/queue/rotational is 1

root@titan:/home/kessaras# cat /sys/block/sd*/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] none
[mq-deadline] none
[mq-deadline] none
[mq-deadline] none

Something is very wrong here. It changes all the hard disks to deadline

Comment: The command doesn't change anything - it simply reports whether a disk is "rotational" (HDD). Rotational = 0 means it's an SSD or other non-spinning drive.

Comment: what do you mean it doesnt change anything ?
And the udev rule written there what does it do ? It is inside a yellow box too.
You mean that im blind or i can't read ?

Comment: My mistake. It seems in latest kernel they removed the schedulers... ???
for f in /sys/block/sd?/queue/scheduler; do printf "$f is "; cat $f; done
/sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler is [mq-deadline] none
/sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler is [mq-deadline] none
/sys/block/sdc/queue/scheduler is [mq-deadline] none
/sys/block/sdd/queue/scheduler is [mq-deadline] none

The article and everything you wrote is fine. It's just that there is only deadline and nothing else to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

```
vi /etc/rc.local
```

Add line

```
for f in /sys/block/sd?/queue/scheduler; do echo "noop" > $f; cat $f; done
```

Then run the command

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```