# Cannot echo "hello" > x.txt even with sudo?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sudo & redirect output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20578/sudo-redirect-output)

I'm trying to create a file in /var/www, but even with `sudo` this fails:

```
user@debVirtual:/var/www$ sudo echo "hello" > f.txt
-bash: f.txt: Permission denied
```

When I use `sudo nano`, I can save something to this file.

Why can't I use `sudo echo`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/sudo-echo-something-etc-privilegedfile-doesnt-work

Comment: For noobs or people like me that read too fast.. it's the `>` (redirection) which is not being sudo'ed.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

The redirection is done by the shell before sudo is even started. So either make sure the redirection happens in a shell with the right permissions

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "hello" > f.txt'
```

or use tee

```
echo "hello" | sudo tee f.txt  # add -a for append (>>)
```

Comment: what if you already used quote and double quote?

Comment: Thanks. Top one didn't work for me on Debian but 2nd option worked perfectly.

Comment: Kind of lengthy + ugly really isn't it.

Comment: If you need multiple lines as stdin input, use `cat <<EOF | sudo tee -a /your/file`, and let your input's last line be `EOF`.

Comment: For those who need to do something similar without logging the information to the console (when you're dealing with private information such as secrets for example), you can find more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18146890/3513260