# How to define the path to MPICH for SSH?

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, cluster, beowulf

I have diploma thesis and follow steps from this manual: [Building a Beowulf Cluster in just 13 steps](https://www.linux.com/blog/building-beowulf-cluster-just-13-steps).

I have a problem with step 11:

> Now we'll define the path to MPICH for SSH. Run the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo echo /home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin >> /etc/environment
> ```

But above command returns this output:

```
bash: /etc/environment: Permission denied
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: "Permission denied" or "No such file or directory"? Did you check  manually if the file is there? If the file is there you must use `echo /home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin | sudo tee -a /etc/environment`.

Comment: Now I have this error:
bash: /etc/environment: Permission denied

I have folder mpich1 in /home/mpiuser

Comment: Which command gives this error - `sudo echo /home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin >> /etc/environment` or `echo /home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin | sudo tee -a /etc/environment`?

Comment: First command, when I put second command I have this output: 
/home/mpiuser/mpich3.2/bin

Comment: Please type `sudo cat /etc/environment` and check your string is added correctly.

Comment: I have this output: 

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

/home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin

Comment: It looks exactly like what you want to do, isn't it?

Comment: Check this site: https://www.linux.com/blog/building-beowulf-cluster-just-13-steps

I don't know what to put in environment file, maybe step 10?

Comment: I think step 11 is not correct. Maybe, you need to append `/home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin` to the value of `PATH` envvar, and the content of `/etc/environment` must be: `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin"` You can edit the file manually or according above example this command could do that: `sudo cat /etc/environment | sed 's/\"$/:\/home\/mpiuser\/mpich1\/bin\"/' | sudo tee /etc/environment`.

Comment: What to do now? Step by step. I don't put nothing in /etc/environment. This file by default. I need only define the path to MPICH for SSH.

Comment: I updated my answer with more detailed explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Your command does not work because the redirection of the output (`>`/`>>`) is not performed by sudo. There are several ways to solve this. For example:

- You can use [pipe](http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/piping.php) (`|`) and performed by [`sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) [`tee`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utee.htm) command with `--append` option:

  ```
  echo /home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
  ```
- Another approach is to run the entire command as `sudo`:

  ```
  sudo bash -c 'echo /home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin >> /etc/environment'
  ```

In result the content of `/etc/environment` will looks something like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
/home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin
```

References:

- [Cannot echo "hello" > x.txt even with sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103643/cannot-echo-hello-x-txt-even-with-sudo)
- [When using sudo with redirection, I get 'permission denied'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/when-using-sudo-with-redirection-i-get-permission-denied)
- [How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr)

**EDIT 1:**

---

However I think this new line in `/etc/environment` will do nothing by itself. To have some meaning this "path" must be appended to the value of `$PATH` envvar.

Ubuntu Documentation [says that](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fenvironment):

> Variable expansion does not work in `/etc/environment`.

So to append `/home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin` to the value of `$PATH`, via single command, you can use this one:

```
cat /etc/environment | sed 's/\"$/:\/home\/mpiuser\/mpich1\/bin\"/' | sudo tee /etc/environment
```

<sup>Where: **(1)** `cat /etc/environment` will print the content of the file; **(2)** `sed '...'` will replace the last quote mark (`"`) with `:/home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin"`; (3) `sudo tee /etc/environment` will rewrite the file.</sup>

In result the content of `/etc/environment` will looks something like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin"
```

<sup>Please, scroll to the end.</sup>

References:

- [linux + sed - replace only the right most side char of string](https://serverfault.com/questions/389046/linux-sed-replace-only-the-right-most-side-char-of-string)

**EDIT 2:**

---

I did a little research and found few advices like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile):

> However, if you need to set that environment variable for all users, I
>   would still not recommend touching `/etc/environment` but creating a
>   file with the file name ending in `.sh` in [`/etc/profile.d`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fprofile.d.2F.2A.sh). The
>   `/etc/profile` script and all scripts in `/etc/profile.d` are the
>   global equivalent of each user's personal `~/.profile` and executed as
>   regular shell scripts by all shells during their initialization.

And [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652151/adding-path-to-path-environment-variable-using-bash-script-in-etc-environment/652169#652169):

> Please avoid modifing system files. Instead you should place an
>   executable script in `/etc/profile.d` (scripts in here got executed
>   for every user) to change `$PATH` value.

According to these advises, let's suppose that you want to create a file named `mpich-path.sh` which is placed in the directory `/etc/profile.d/`. This can be done by the command:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin"' | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/mpich-path.sh
```

In result the content of the new file `/etc/profile.d/mpich-path.sh` will looks like this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin"
```

Logout and login back into the system and type `echo $PATH` to check the result.

**EDIT 3:**

---

I don't know about the other steps in the manual that you have follow, but apart from step 11, step 10 also does not seem completely clear.

This part:

```
export PATH=/home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin:$PATH    # assigns a new value and exports the variable
export PATH                                   # exports the variable
```

must be:

```
PATH=/home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin:$PATH           # assigns a new value
export PATH                                   # exports the variable
```

or just:

```
export PATH=/home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin:$PATH    # assigns a new value and exports the variable
```

And it will produce the same result as step 11. So this part is unnecessary.

The new thing here is this part:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/mpiuser/mpich1/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

But, maybe, it can be included into the file - `/etc/profile.d/mpich-path.sh` - who we created above.

Comment: I am doing your steps approach 1 & 2. What now ?

Comment: Via login as root I doing this command without error:

sudo echo /home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin >> /etc/environment

Now in /etc/environment I have line: /home/mpiuser/mpich1/bin

Line upper: PATH= ... games is ok? I don't must delete this line?

Comment: @StanislavI have made a little survey for you, please check "EDIT" section of my answer :)

Comment: I don't know what to do but thanks for information.

Comment: All this is according to step 11. If you have done this go to steps 12 and 13. @Stanislav

Comment: Send me all what I need for step 11. Step by step.