# Lubuntu USB device is not showing up

Tags: usb, lubuntu

I want to connect my ClimeMet CM2000 to Lubuntu but when I plug in, it doesnt recognize any change (through lsusb).

I have tested with other usb devices such as my mouse and phone and they show up just fine.

I have plugged into my windows computer and works just fine. Does anyone have any ideas?

My lsusb output is:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0001 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0001 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0001 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0001 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


[ 2657.612216] usb 5-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 2657.860178] usb 5-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
```

[image]
Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Hi, I've added the lines, not sure which ones are new so did a before and after, is this enough to help?

Comment: Okay, done now.

Comment: Try adding a line to /etc/modprobe.d/options: `options usbcore use_both_schemes=y` then reboot. [Source](https://www.spinics.net/lists/usb/msg02644.html)

Comment: So i'm running, "options usbcore use_both_schemes=y" ? Says "options:command not found"

Comment: Ok, am i doing this right?: "sudo echo "options usbcore use_both_schemes=y" >> /etc/modprobe.d/options: " -now i get permission denied .

Comment: [Sudo echo doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103643/). Try it this way: `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/test.conf` then add the line, CTRL+X to save and exit (follow the prompts), then reboot.

Comment: The line is now in the file and i rebooted however still can't see my device in lsusb. Is it worth while seeing the dmesg again?

Comment: [  561.924041] usb 5-1: device not accepting address 9, error -71,
[  561.924084] usb usb5-port1: unable to enumerate USB device.

Comment: Well, I'll step aside and let somebody else help with the next idea.